# fullscreen centering html5 video live feed

Tags: html, css, video, center, fullscreen

I want to have a fullscreen live feed from my device's camera, but centered. So if i have my face in the middle, i want that on any device to have my face in the middle (whatever aspect ratio (landscape <-> portrait))

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Picture time!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" onclick="snapshot()"></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="display: none"></canvas>

    <script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#video {
    position: absolute;
}
```

JS function that does the rescaling:

```
function rescaleEverthing(){
    var jqueryVideo = $("#video");
    var body = $("body");

    var videoWidth = jqueryVideo.width();
    var videoHeight = jqueryVideo.height();
    var bodyWidth = body.width();
    var bodyHeight = body.height();

    var videoRatio = videoWidth / videoHeight;
    var bodyRatio = bodyWidth / bodyHeight;

    if(vi)
    if(videoRatio > bodyRatio){
        jqueryVideo.css("height", "100%");
        jqueryVideo.css("transform", "translateX(-" + (videoWidth-bodyWidth)/2 + "px)");
    } else {
        jqueryVideo.css("width", "100%");
        jqueryVideo.css("transform", "translateY(-" + (videoHeight-bodyHeight)/2 + "px)");
    }
}
```

But when you run this, the middle of my video is not in the middle when portrait mode

Can someone help? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JS to do it, look at [object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) option:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}

video {
  width:100%; height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<video video-player controls id="video_player" src="http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_1280x720_60fps_6000k.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: Just needed to change the object-fit from contain to cover to have exactly what i wanted! And super thanks for the fast response!

Comment: @JavascriptDeveloper, happy to help!